# Can't send mail using mail-service.xml of jboss 5.0 runtime server in spring MVC

Tags: java, xml, spring, email

I am trying to send a mail using mail-service.xml.But I didn't get any exception from the code.But no message is send.I attach my code with this.I am using spring with hibernate.So I have serviceconfig xml file and servlet xml file .

index.jsp

```
<body>
<h1>Mail</h1>
<form name="mailsend" method="post" action="mailsend.do" id="employeeCreation">
<input type="submit" name="mailbutton" value="SEND" id="mailbutton">
</form>
</body>
```

servlet.xml

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
    <props>
    <prop key="mailsend.do">MailController</prop>                   
    </props>
    </property>     
</bean>
<bean id="MailController" class="com.sample.web.MailController">
    <property name="successView"><value>Home</value></property>
    <property name="failedView"><value>../../index</value></property>       
    <property name="mailservice" ref="mailservice"></property>          
    <property name="dao" ref="dao"></property>
</bean>
    <bean id="mailSender"
        class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
           <property name="session" ref="mailSession" ></property> 
  </bean>
<bean id="contentMessage"
        class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
     <!--    <property name="session" ref="mailSession" ></property> -->
</bean>
<bean id="mailSession"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/Mail" />
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true"></property>
</bean>
```

MailController.java

```
public class MailController extends AbstractController{
private String successView;
private String failedView;
private DAO dao;
private MailService mailservice;

public String getSuccessView() {
    return successView;
}

public void setSuccessView(String successView) {
    this.successView = successView;
}

public String getFailedView() {
    return failedView;
}

public void setFailedView(String failedView) {
    this.failedView = failedView;
}


public MailService getmailservice() {
    return mailservice;
}

public void setmailservice(MailService mailservice) {
    this.mailservice = mailservice;
}


public DAO getDao() {
    return dao;
}

public void setDao(DAO dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
}
public ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
{
           try{
            SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
            simpleMailMessage.setSubject("Mail testing ");
            simpleMailMessage.setText("Mail success");
            System.out.println("ENTER CONTROLLER");
            String message="Hai";
            String receiverMailId="*******@gmail.com";
            System.out.println("START SENDING");
            mailservice.sendMail(message,receiverMailId);
            System.out.println("Sending success:)");
            return (new ModelAndView(this.getSuccessView()));
           }catch(Exception e){
               System.out.println("EXCEPTION");
               e.printStackTrace();
               return (new ModelAndView(this.getFailedView()));
           }

  }     
}
```

MailService.java

```
public interface MailService {

void sendMail(String message,String receiverMailId);

}
```

MailServiceImpl.java

```
public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {   
private JavaMailSender  mailSender;
public JavaMailSender getMailSender() {
    return mailSender;
}
public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
    this.mailSender = mailSender;
}

private SimpleMailMessage contentMessage;


public SimpleMailMessage getContentMessage() {
    return contentMessage;
}
public void setContentMessage(SimpleMailMessage contentMessage) {
    this.contentMessage = contentMessage;
}

@Override
public void sendMail(String message, String receiverMailId) {
    try{            
    MimeMessage message1 = this.getMailSender().createMimeMessage();        
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION IN IMPL  "+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

serviceconf.xml

```
<bean id="mailservice" parent="txProxyTemplate">
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="com.sample.service.impl.MailServiceImpl">
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender"></property>             
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and in my mail-service.xml of jboss5.0 server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- $Id: mail-service.xml 62350 2007-04-15 16:50:12Z dimitris@jboss.org $ -->
<server>
<!-- ======================================================== -->
<!-- Mail Connection Factory                         -->
<!-- ====================================================== -->
<mbean code="org.jboss.mail.MailService"
     name="jboss:service=Mail">
<attribute name="JNDIName">java:/Mail</attribute>
<attribute name="User">******@gmail.com</attribute>
<attribute name="Password">*******</attribute>
<attribute name="Configuration">
  <!-- A test configuration -->
  <configuration>
<property name="mail.smtp.auth" value="true"/>
    <property name="mail.smtp.starttls.enable" value="true"/>
    <property name="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class" value="javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"/>
    <!-- Change to your mail server prototocol -->
    <property name="mail.store.protocol" value="pop3"/>
    <property name="mail.transport.protocol" value="smtp"/>

    <!-- Change to the user who will receive mail  -->
    <property name="mail.user" value="nobody"/>

    <!-- Change to the mail server  -->
    <property name="mail.pop3.host" value="pop3.gmail.com"/>

    <!-- Change to the SMTP gateway server -->
    <property name="mail.smtp.host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>

    <!-- The mail server port -->
    <property name="mail.smtp.port" value="465"/>

    <!-- Change to the address mail will be from  -->
    <property name="mail.from" value="******@gmail.com"/>

    <!-- Enable debugging output from the javamail classes -->
    <property name="mail.debug" value="false"/>
  </configuration>
</attribute>
<depends>jboss:service=Naming</depends>
</mbean>

</server>
```

The output of the result is:

```
ENTER CONTROLLER
START SENDING
Sending success:)
```

It doesn't show any exception.But the message was not send?What will do?Is there any mistake when connecting with mail-service.xml?Please anyone help me to solve the isssue...

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Your mail is not got send because you have not called the sent() function still. Your Code missing the send() method API Call.

use

```
public void sendMail(String message, String receiverMailId) {
try{            
MimeMessage message1 = this.getMailSender().createMimeMessage(); 
send(message1)       ;
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("EXCEPTION IN IMPL  "+e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}
}

Comment: I add Transport.send(message1);.But shows exception EXCEPTION IN IMPL  javax.mail.SendFailedException: No recipient addresses
15:51:59,821 ERROR [STDERR] javax.mail.SendFailedException: No recipient addresses
15:51:59,821 ERROR [STDERR]  at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:128)

Comment: Check in other answer

Answer (score 0):

Beacsue you have not set the to and from of mail:
set  those as:

```
MimeMessage message1  = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message1 , true);

        helper.setFrom("xyz@zyz");
        helper.setTo("xyz@zyz");
        helper.setSubject("xyz");
```

Comment: Again show the exception.Is there any ,mistake the connection with mail-service.xml file?Is the coding is correct?I am new in spring with hibernate.

Comment: What is the exception